# Line vs Statement coverage in SQL Cover

Tags: unit-testing, code-coverage, redgate, tsqlt

I am trying to use SQL Cover library in my project to find the code coverage,

I have tried using Redgate SQL Test previously for same purpose but with SQL cover the number of lines are almost double to that considered in SQL Test.

E.g.
SQL Test : Total Lines considered for coverage is 10000

SQL Cover: Total Lines considered for coverage is 19850

I want to know why there is so much difference in both when SQL Test internally use SQL Cover library, and is there a way to resolve this.

Comment: Is SQL Test reporting exactly 10,000? If so, this is suspicious and I wonder whether this is a hard coded upper limit?

Comment: No that's like particularly for my code, it is not hardcoded. If I remove code this count is varying.